# Facebook Social Graph Whitelist Partner

Tags: facebook, mp3, facebook-opengraph, whitelist

It appears that the only way to be able to post an mp3 player into a users timeline via our website / application is to be a whitelisted partner

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

Does anyone know how to go about getting whitelisted?

Thanks